# SQL Server/C#: Drop Multiple Tables/ExecuteNonQuery Results

Tags: c#, sql-server

Good morning everyone,

The short and sweet question is: ***what will SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() return in the case of the query being multiple drop table statements?***

For example, if I pass five tables to my drop method, and it builds a query with five drop table statements, ***what will ExecuteNonQuery return***? I think it will return a value of negative one (based on MSDN), hoping it will return the exact count of tables that were dropped successfully, and hoping that it will not return the number of rows cumulatively removed from the database since this would be extremely excessive and most likely not the answer.

### CODE

```
string query = string.Empty;
foreach (string name in tableNames)
    query += $"DROP TABLE [{name}]; ";

using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn)
    droppedTableCount = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(); // Returns number of rows affected.

return droppedTableCount;
```

### MSDN

> You can use the ExecuteNonQuery to perform catalog operations (for example, querying the structure of a database or creating database objects such as tables), or to change the data in a database without using a DataSet by executing UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE statements. Although the ExecuteNonQuery returns no rows, any output parameters or return values mapped to parameters are populated with data. For UPDATE, INSERT, and DELETE statements, the return value is the number of rows affected by the command. When a trigger exists on a table being inserted or updated, the return value includes the number of rows affected by both the insert or update operation and the number of rows affected by the trigger or triggers. For all other types of statements, the return value is -1. If a rollback occurs, the return value is also -1.

Comment: What happened when you actually ran the code?

Comment: Unable to do this due to restrictions in the work environment. The people with permissions to perform such actions on the database won't be back for another couple days. Kind of in a time crunch.

Comment: It may take longer, but you could do each query separately with a counter that goes up 1 each time the query is successful.

Comment: Can't you try this on local copy of the database on your computer? A sample test database may be?

Comment: @jdwee I have thought about doing that at this point

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Unable to use localdb in my current work environment.